# A PDF viewer with a toolbar actions

Tags: pdf, drupal, content-management-system, viewer

I want a Drupal Module who let to the Adminintrator to upload pdf files and the users to read them in a viewer with a Toolbar that contains print, download and quit boutons like the [calameo](http://www.calameo.com/) website.

The possibility to have statistics on user's Toolbar actions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the solution that I found :

1-Installation of the [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [SWF Tools](http://drupal.org/project/swftools).

2-Configuration of the [FlowPlayer 3](http://flowplayer.org/) player to be the Default player for FLV movies.

3-Creation of a new content that contains two fileds: one to upload the swf file and the second to upload its twin in pdf to be downloaded by the members.

4-The use of [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org/) to covert the pdf files to swf files

For futur optimum solutions, I migrate this question to the official drupal forum
http://drupal.org/node/833088