# modules to load .docx & .pdf file in drupal

Tags: pdf, drupal-6, drupal-7, document, document-management

Hello I am looking to see if there are any modules for drupal 6 or 7, which would allow basic document management functionalities and allow to view .docx and pdf documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For viewing PDF: http://drupal.org/project/fileviewer or [A PDF viewer with a toolbar actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064879/a-pdf-viewer-with-a-toolbar-actions)

Concerning .docx files, I think you may need to actually add mime type support at the webserver level in order for it to work with a viewer (http://drupal.org/node/177256)

Here's your standard drupal file management plugins: http://drupal.org/node/265416

If you're not opposed to integrating google docs, you may be able to do more with it. If so try this module for integrated file viewing: http://drupal.org/project/gdoc_field and this for basic integration with google docs http://drupal.org/project/google_docs (not maintained past 6x)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Check [elfinder](http://drupal.org/project/elfinder) if you are looking for a nice UI for managing your files and folders.